# vue.js Cannot find element #app

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

learning custom plugins, I am trying to test w a virtual DOM

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyPlugin from '@/plugins/MyPlugin'

Vue.use(MyPlugin)

describe('MyPlugin', () => {
  let vm

  beforeEach(() => {
    vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div id="app" class="container" v-demo:hello.a.b="msg"></div>',
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        msg: 'hello!'
      }
    }).$mount()
  })

  it('should run', () => {
    Vue.myMethod()
    console.log('INNER: ', vm.$el.innerHTML)
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })
})
```

but I get an error :

ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app'

isn't already defined in the template ??

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `el` property is used to specify the element currently in the DOM to mount the Vue instance to.

You can't specify that element within the Vue instance's template because it needs to mount somewhere on the DOM before it can render.

You need to add an element with id `#app` to your html outside of your Vue instance and remove the `id="app"` from the div in its template.